# Браузер не использует шрифт с компьютера⁠

Tags: шрифты, браузер

Есть сайт, который использует достаточно экзотический шрифт (**не встроенный**, по инструкции использования этого раздела сайта требуется его установка на компьютер).

```
<span style="font-family:'Irmologion ieUcs';" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1679396876420_476">w3 мнэ2 глумлz1хусz сэдz1щіи во вратэ1хъ</span>
```

И в браузере отображается кракозябра.

Однако, на компьютер используемый шрифт установлен, и в блокноте и ворде этот же текст (просто скопированный, control+c - control+v) отображается так, как нужно.

Таким образом, складывается полное ощущение, что шрифт не видит именно браузер.
И собственно вопрос, как это можно исправить?
(Нет, в гугле не забанили, но как я не формулирую запрос - получаю ответы не для пользователя, а для разраба, как встроить шрифт в сайт..)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не подключили шрифт. Прикол в том, что он у вас имеется на компьютере, если у вас Windows - в поиске наберите "Шрифты" и зайдите в эту папку, там найдёте используемый вами шрифт. Но когда вы пытаетесь загрузить сайт не локально, он не знает откуда брать эти шрифты. В идеале вам нужно скачать шрифты на сайт и установить подключение, а не тянуть с интернета. Благодаря этому не будет подключения к стороннему сайту.
И что за шрифт такой сказочный)).

Comment: Проблема в том, что сайт не мой - мне им нужно пользоваться. Советов про подключение шрифтов к сайту я наслушался и на других ресурсах, и весь гугл в них.. А ведь у других пользователей того же сайта (одногрупников моих) таких проблем нет - они установили шрифт на комп и работают с сайтом нормально
(PS. Шрифт - церковно-славянский, таким пишут богослужебные тексты. А поскольку в ЦСЯ знаков больше, чем в русском - то к кириллице добавлена латиница)

Comment: @EugeneGodgiven вы случайно не в Safari открываете? Просто зачастую были проблемы с шрифтами не поддерживаемыми или некорректно отображаемыми Safari

Comment: Нет - firefox 110 + ubuntu 22.04, если это важно

Comment: @EugeneGodgiven в Консоли браузера нет ошибок? Должно же быть написано, таких-то шрифтов не обнаружено?

Comment: В общем вам никто я так понял здесь не поможет, так как не видим проблему.